# Possible to add a `Find "string"' to the Toolbar?

Tags: front-end, interface, system, user-interface

It would be nice to have a persistent "Find" feature on the tool bar.

I find the FindAndReplaceDialog to be clumsy on MacOs.

I could do this with a DockedCell, but then I would need to do it for each notebook. I suppose a Palette would work--but I think that many others would find this useful as well?

@John Fultz, sorry, I had been meaning to suggest this in prerelease, but never got around to it.  If it could have autocompletion, so much the better. (addendum: I'm also curious why Documentation never implemented autocomplete.

Comment: Why not you use a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @maeinss Because it pulls up MacOs's FindAndReplaceDialog.  That dialog is a bit clunky because I have to shift the window focus, and then after I use Find once, the FindAndReplaceDialog goes away, and I have to use the shortcut to bring it up to find subsequent results from Find.

Comment: Yes the Find and Replace box is not very good in particular because it may hide what has been found.  The palette is not much better. The DockCell is a great idea.  Making it permanent is a matter of style.  You could just check how it is done is style sheets.  All style sheets have the same DockCell setup.